# Term for expectation of early defection in a collusion situation?

Tags: terminology, behavioral-economics, economics, game-theory

My background is in economics, so my apologies if my description here is unclear.

In a paper, [Dong (2019)](https://www.mendeley.com/catalogue/8889aa48-dbef-303a-8896-2880d0d6376d/?utm_source=desktop&utm_medium=1.19.8&utm_campaign=open_catalog&userDocumentId=%7B1df87455-19cc-4494-af93-e274716a758e%7D) mentions that:

> On the other hand, the anticipated costs of collusion could decrease
> if firms expect to be the first to apply for leniency, which would
> enable them to pay lower fines than in the case without leniency and
> impose extra costs on their rivals (e.g., the negative effects noted
> by McCutcheon, 1997; Spagnolo, 2000; Motta and Polo, 2003; Chen and
> Rey, 2013). This would stabilize existing cartels or even induce the
> formation of new ones

I understand that if every firm thinks that it will be an early "defector" before joining a new cartel, then this will encourage the establishment of new cartels.  **Is there a term for this phenomenon where participants are more likely to collude in expectation that they will be first to defect if things go wrong?**

This is related to the standard [prisoner's dilemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prisoner%27s_dilemma), where the first to defect receives a lower sentence, but my question is about an increase in the likelihood of colluding with others in the first place in expectation of defection in case of being caught.